# Growth of quadratic form

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $f(x,y,z)=ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dxy+exz+fyx$ a quadratic form. So my question is if it's possible that for three sequences of natural numbers $(m_{1,k})$, $(m_{2,k})$ and $(m_{3,k})$ we have the following behavior
$$
f(m_{1,k},m_{2,k},m_{3,k})\leq (m_{1,k}+m_{2,k}+m_{3,k})+\sqrt{k}
$$

and the sequence has the property that there is $a_1,a_2,a_3$ positive real number such that
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{(a_1m_{1,k}+a_2m_{2,k}+a_3m_{3,k})^2}{k}=a \in (0,\infty)
$$

or we can conclude that $f$ needs to be zero?

Comment: Is the a in the limit the same a as the one in $f$? In any case, this is very possible as stated, just take $f(x, y, z) = - y^2$ and $m_{2, k} = \sqrt{ka}$, $m_{1, k} = m_{3, k} = 0$. You probably want to add some positivity condition or bound $f$ in absolute value.